# Powershell : set_InnerText function not appearing for XML

Tags: windows-8, powershell, xml

$xml contains a xml document

```
$e = $xml.CreateElement("Pass2")
```

`$e.set_InnerText ("p2")`  --> This command errors out

`$e.SetAttribute("Pass2","p221")` --> This works, but is not what I need

Essentially I want to check for the existence of an attribute in a xml file and create it if it doesn't exist. This is the code I am trying to use for creating the attribute, after which I do an

`AppendChild`

I need it in the format

```
<Pass2>p221</Pass2>
```

Error message:

At line:1 char:18

```
+ $e.set_InnerText ("p2")
+                  ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I'm using Windows 8, and the guide I am following ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/10/07/adding-elements-to-xml-objects-with-windows-powershell.aspx ) is dated 2006, so is there a syntax change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `$e.set_InnerText` and `("p2")`.

Comment: The function not appearing in Autocomplete threw me off ...